# Convert string to int in Hibernate order criterion

Tags: hibernate

Basically, my question is the same as this one, but for Java's (JBoss) Hibernate:  [How can we order a column as int using hibernate criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871131/how-can-we-order-a-column-as-int-using-hibernate-criteria-api)

I want to create an order restriction with a cast to int from a string column. Something like

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("cast(id as int)"));
```

The exception is "Could not resolve property: cast(id as int) of [Class]". I've tried both cast( as ) and convert(,) with int and integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Despite the topic is old and may be the problem were solved, I'll post solution. Maybe it will be helpful in future for someone.

```
criteria.addOrder(new org.hibernate.criterion.Order("anystring", true) {
            @Override
            public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
                return "cast(id as int)";
            }
        });
```

Comment: This solution works if you don't want to specify ascending or descending, because second parameter is used in original toSqlString method. If you override it you have to add asc or desc in the end of string on your own.

Comment: KarolR, that's why the method is called toSqlString. You can write your own order as you wish, but you should specify the whole order string. And one more - there is always direction for order, by default "asc" is used so "cast(id as int)" is actually "cast(id as int) asc", but you can skip it. You can specify complex ordering, how hibernate should decide where to put direction, which was specified as parameter?

Comment: it is indeed very helpful and you just saved me from spending lots of time to refactor my criteria code as sql just for order issue. +1 for both your comments and answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the column contains integer values, the best solution is to map it as an integer rather than a String.

If, for obscure reasons, this is not possible, you could add a integer field annotated with [`@Formula("cast(id) as number")`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6481) in your entity and order on this field.

Comment: Due generic calls and having some tables with string identifiers, it was decided to convert everything to String. Anyway, I'm not being able to use the Formula annotation due to error exceptions on the maven build (in the hibernate3-maven-plugin), so I can't test it and I'll just leave this issue on stand-by. Tks

Comment: it should be `@Formula("cast(id as NUMBER(10,0))")`