# Hibernate Criteria DetachedCriteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have an issue with Hibernate as although I am setting following

```
DetachedCriteria timestampFilter = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FormParams.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("id.keyName","DataSetName"))
.setProjection(Projections.property("id.keyName"));
Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria query = currentSession.createCriteria(FormInstance.class)
.add(Property.forName("formParams").eq(timestampFilter))
```

From which I expect it to do a sensible query based on the keyName, the SQL generated is:

```
batchjobpa4_.FORM_ID where this_.FORM_ID = (select this_.KEY_NAME as y0_ from az_alpha.FORM_PARAMS this_ where this_.KEY_NAME=?)
```

From my understanding this returns the keyName field, and equals it to the FORM_ID field which is the index int, while keyName is a string. How can I make it equal the proper field ?

Comment: can you format your code snippet?

Comment: @Vinit Prajapati Have formatted it now

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545664/convert-string-to-int-in-hibernate-order-criterion

Comment: This does not solve my issue as I am not getting the error he is, just 0 items returned, and keyName is a word that is not a number so casting will not work, unless I am reading the sql wrong, it is getting the keyName that satisfy the condition and try to find ID that match keyName. I am expecting the sql in the select to be select this. FORM_ID....